# Вывод одномерного массива VBA Excel

Tags: массивы, excel, vba

Мне необходимо вывести одномерный массив в Excel'е в строку.
Как это можно реализовать?

```
Function FUN3(Aa As Integer, Bb As Integer)
Dim masA() As Double
Dim masB() As Double
ReDim masA(Aa To Bb)
ReDim masB(Aa To Bb)
Dim Y As Double, R As Integer, sum As Double
sum = 0
For i = Aa To Bb Step 1
masA(i) = Rnd * 100 - 15
masB(i) = ((1 - masA(i)) / (Aa + Bb)) * (Sin(masA(i))) ^ 2
Next i
For i = Aa To Bb Step 1
sum = sum + masB(i)
Next i

FUN3 = sum
End Function
```

Comment: Какой именно массив имеется в виду? Функция `FUN3` возвращает не массив, а число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так

```
Sub ArrayToSheet()
    Dim arr(1 To 10)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr): arr(i) = i: Next
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1) = arr
End Sub
```